# Wiring a ceiling fan w/light to old wiring of 4 white, 2 black

Tags: electrical, wiring

When I removed the existing light fixture, it was connected to two white wires and one black wire. However, there are two white and one black nutted off together, not being used. So I thought to use the existing configuration. I connected the black and blue wire from the ceiling fan to the existing black wire, the white from the fan to the two white wires and the green to ground.  Nothing works when turning on the switch.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it two white nutted together and one separate black with a nut?  Except in special cases white and black should not be joined.

Comment: Does the fan have pull chains for the light and fan? Did you try pulling the chains.

Comment: You may need some test equipment to figure this out.

Comment: Are you **sure** it's 2 white and 1 black nutted off together? I would expect 2 black and 1 white.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring involved please?

Comment: *"However, there are two white and one black nutted off together, not being used."* That's a misconception. Wires that are nutted together are almost certainly in use, even if they don't connect to the fixture. Wires not in use tend to be connected to nothing, **not** to other wires.